# Evolution equations of a 2-gender age-structure model?

Tags: population-dynamics, population-biology

*This sounds a bit complicated but I want to grab more feelings on age-structured problems. Less than 2 days to the exam so I appreciate any help.*

So suppose we get 4 age classes in a population census and we don't count the people in the eldest age class again. We model females and males separately. Let $u_{i,n}$ and $v_{i,n}$ be the number of females and males in age class $i$ at census $n$, respectively. $s_i$ and $t_i$ are the fraction of females and males, respectively, surviving from age class $i − 1$ to $i$. $m_i$ is the (expected) number of children from a female in age class $i$.

If a fraction $\alpha$ of births are females and $1 − \alpha$ are males, what are the evolution equations for (1) $u_{1, n}$ to $u_{4, n}$ and (2) $v_{1, n}$ to $v_{4, n}$ respectively?

1. I tried putting forward the Leslie matrix for female: $$\begin{bmatrix} \alpha s_1 m_1 & \alpha s_1 m_2 & \alpha s_1 m_3 & \alpha s_1 m_4 \\ s_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & s_3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & s_4 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ Is this correct?
2. If I try to repeat the thought process in part 1, we must use $u_{i, n}$ to write out the equations for males in the 1st age group, i.e. $v_{1, n+1}$ (unless both gender can give birth): $$v_{1, n+1} = (1-\alpha)t_1\left(\sum_{j=1}^4 u_{j, n} m_j\right).$$ Is this a way to determine "the evolution equation for $v_{i, n+1}$ in terms of the population structure at census
   $n$"?
3. In case I have to find the gender ratio (e.g. for a certain age class or overall) in census $n+1$ or in long run, should I find the largest eigenvalue of both Leslie matrices for both gender, and proceed to find the respective eigenvectors for both gender, and then add the terms together to compare?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good luck on your exams! I sure am glad I’m not the one taking them. (I had a dream last night about needing to solve a math problem much simpler than this one. Unfortunately the numbers kept changing!)